# Is there a tool to check filenames before burning to discs?

Tags: dvd, filenames, dvd-burning, nero, optical-media

Is there a software that can check for filenames in a certain folder so that there wouldn't be any error when trying to burn those files into a DVD or any optical media?

I always burn different kinds of files for my collection and often times I get a file rename error when using Nero. Do those files still get burned to the disc even if I get those errors?

Is there a separate tool for Nero or other application to check for the filenames before burning them to disc. It really sucks when an application tells you that there's an error if you have already burned the files to the disc. I want to know which files should be renamed before I even burn them so that I won't be wasting anything

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by a "file rename error?"

Comment: By "file name error", do you mean "long file names" or "invalid characters" that may be in file names?

Comment: What filesystem are you putting on the DVD? (ISO 9660, 9660+RockRidge, 9660+Joliet, and UFS are the main possibilities.) And what operating system are you using?

Comment: @giless:iso 9660, @mehper:yep.does it get burned to the disc even if I get those errors?

Comment: [There are various ways to find files whose names are too long](https://superuser.com/q/647858/241386). ISO9660 supports only [8.3 or 30-character names (depending on the level) with 8-level directories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660#Limitations)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention your operating system, so I'll give a solution using POSIX tools, since they're available for every major operating system. They're available on all unix-like systems, but you have to install them separately on Windows ([Microsoft's Services for Unix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Services_for_UNIX), [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), [GNU Win32 utilities](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/), [Msys](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSYS), ...).

The `find` command¹ looks in a directory and its subdirectories recursively for files matching certain criteria. For example, the following command shows files under the current directory whose name contain one of the characters `:`, `;` or `"`, or than are more than 64 characters long.

```
find . -name '*[:;"]*' -o -name '?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????*'
```

¹ <sub>The POSIX one. Windows has an unrelated command with the same name.</sub>

Comment: I feel pain... `find . -name '*[:;"]*' -o -regex '.{64,}'`

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run above command (the prettier one ;) but I did not succeed) on Ubuntu 20.04 (hosted by Win10 via WSL 2). So I propose the following commands:

To find the file names (excluding path) greater than 64:

```
find . -name '*[:;"]*' -o -regextype grep -regex '.*/[^/]\{64,\}'
```

To find the file names (including path) greater than 64:

```
find . -name '*[:;"]*' -o -regextype grep -regex '\./.\{64,\}'
```